# Interperting hex commands for a camera on a data sheet

Tags: camera, arduino, command, hex

I'm reading this data sheet for a camera.

[Datasheet](http://www.electronics123.net/amazon/datasheet/C329_SPI_UM-V1.1.pdf)

I have my Arduino communicating with the camera over SPI and can send it a command to take a picture.

The last step is to send a command to retrieve the data, which I'm stuck on.

On page 4 the command DATA is

> FF FF FF 0x0A 0X05 Length Byte 0 Length Byte 1 Length Byte 2'

So in code the command would look like this. But how do I figure out what Length Byte 0, Byte 1 Length Byte 2 are??

```
uint8_t DataCmd[8] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0a, 0x05, ?, ?, ?};
```

On page 6 it says

> Image Length = len 0 + Len 1 * 100h + Len 2 * 10000h

What does this mean? And how to I translate it into the three parameters that I need for my command?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read, the DATA command is a command sent BY the camera to you. The flow chart at page 9 shows what it does

1. When the camera receives "get picture",
2. is the picture ready? if not send a NAK and return
3. if it is send an ACK
4. send the DATA command (with the length)
5. send the picture data
6. wait for the host to send an ACK

Page 10 has the steps you have to perform. I'll copy them here for future reference:

- Establish communication with the camera
- Send command INIT (e.g. FFFFFF0100870107h)
- Wait for the ACK (e.g. FFFFFF0E01nn0000h)
- Send command SELECT IMAGE QUALITY (e.g. FFFFFF1000000000h)
- Wait for the ACK (e.g. FFFFFF0E10nn0000h)
- Send command GET PICTURE (e.g. FFFFFF0405000000h)
- Wait for the ACK (e.g. FFFFFF0E04nn0000h)
- Wait for the DATA (e.g. FFFFFF0AnnL0L1L2h)
- Receive Image Data

The DATA packet contains L0, L1 and L2, which contain the data image length. L0 is the low-order byte, so if L0 = 0x45, L1 = 0x23, L2 = 0x01 the total length will be 0x012345 = L0 + L1 * 0x100 + L2 * 0x1000; this means that the image is 0x12345 = 74565 bytes, so you know how many bytes you will receive before actually receiving them